# Insert element inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function

```js
checkName(output) {

  output.filter((NewData) => {
    return this.props.elements.filter((OldData) => {
      if (NewData.key == OldData.key) {
        NewData.name = OldData.name,
          //there i need to add another element 
          // Need to add newData.number = OldData.number
      }
      return NewData
    })
  })
  
  return output
}
```

and I call this function like:

```
const named = this.checkName(product.rows)
```

Now I need to add to my product's array that I passed to checkName the value "OldData.Number" to  "newData.Number" that is not defined in product (so I need to create this field)

For example:

**Product before the checkName function**

```
product.rows = [NewData.name]
```

**Product after the checkName function**

```
product.rows = [NewData.name="value of OldData.name", NewData.number="value of OldData.number"]
```

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: Your use of filter() is incorrect. When all you need is a loop use a loop method like `forEach()` or a `for()` loop. `filter()` returns a new array

Comment: Why it is incorrect??

Comment: Please show data in valid JavaScript syntax; the current "Product after the checkName function" is not valid.

Comment: You never use the results of `filter()` is why. You are simply using it to loop over the array which is not what filter is for

Comment: @charlietfl I should use the filter only to check if NewData.key is equal to OldData.key

Comment: [The function passed to `filter` should return a Boolean indicating whether the element passes the filter or not.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters)

Comment: @HereticMonkey i know that is invalid, this is what I should obtain or similar

Comment: use map() and forEach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 confusing things in your code:

- You are using `filter` to execute an action in each member of the `output` array. However, filter should be used to... well, filter that array, meaning that is should not modify it, just return a sub-set of it. Instead, you might want to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). However, taking into accound the next bullet, probably you want to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- You are modifying the array passed to the `checkName` function. This is confusing and can lead to hard-to-find bugs. Instead, make your function "pure", meaning that it should not mutate its inputs, instead just return the data you need from it.

I would suggest some implementation like this one:

```
checkName(output){
    return output.map((NewData) => {
        // find the old data item corresponding to the current NewData
        const OldData = this.props.elements.find(x => x.key === NewData.key);
    
        if (OldData) {
            // If found, return a clone of the new data with the old data name
        
            // This uses the spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
            return {
                ...NewData, // Clone the NewData object
                name: OldData.name, // set the value found in OldData.name in the "name" field of the cloned object
                number: OldData.number, // You can do the same for each field for which you want to replace the value cloned from NewValue
            };
        } else {
            // Otherwise, just return a clone of the NewData
            return { ...NewData };
        }
    }
}
```

The usage would be like this:

```
const named = this.checkName(product.rows)
```

Be aware that the `product.rows` array won't be modified!

Comment: ok I'm trying this and it seems what I search!! Only a question if I would to return in the if(OldData) condition also `"Document.Sender.number: OldData.number"`, how can I do?

Comment: Document.Sender.Number is not in NewDate

Comment: You can add any property you want to take from the `OldData` like this: `return { ...NewData, name: OldData.name, number: OldData.number };` I'll update the code with some comments to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can get keys and values of the old object.

```
const keys = Object.keys(oldObject);
const values = Object.values(oldObject);

// or
const [keys, values] = Object.entries(oldObject);
```

After, you will create a loop with all keys of oldObject, and insert in newObject like a array.

```
keys.forEach( (key, index) => newObject[key] = values[index]);

// or

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  newObject[key] = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map like this.

```
checkName(output){
return output.map(( NewData) =>{
 this.props.elements.forEach((OldData) => {
 if (NewData.key == OldData.key) {
     NewData.name = OldData.name;
     NewData.number = OldData.number;
   }
})
 return NewData;
})
 // return output;
}
```

Comment: I have tried in this way but I received undefined as output